# How to make a stoppable thread with a target function that is an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Suppose I would like to run a function, called `run_forever()`, in a thread, but still have it 'stoppable' by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I've seen ways of doing this using a `StoppableThread` subclass of `threading.Thread`, but these seem to involve 'copying' the target function into that subclass. I would like to instead keep the function 'where it is'.

Consider the following example:

```
import time
import threading

def run_forever():  # An externally defined function which runs indefinitely
    while True:
        print("Hello, world!")
        time.sleep(1)

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            run_forever()             # This doesn't work
            # print("Hello, world!")      # This does
            self._stop.wait(1)

thread = StoppableThread()
thread.start()
time.sleep(5)
thread.stop()
```

The target function `run_forever` is itself a while-loop which never exits. However, to get the desired behavior the `wait()` command has to be inside that while-loop, as I understand it.

Is there any way of achieving the desired behavior without modifying the `run_forever()` function?

Comment: If you simply want your program to be " 'stoppable' by pressing Cntrl+C" - which I interpret to mean "will not hang when I try to kill the program" - you can set the daemon attribute in the Thread object to True as such:  `thread = StoppableThread(daemon=True)`.

Comment: [Billy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7007605/billy), I already have such an implementation with daemonized threads, but these are stopped abruptly. I would like something that stops gracefully.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot change the `run_forever` function, I think your best chance would be to access the platform API directly, similarly to the second example in the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/7007605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it's possible.
BTW, have you tried the second solution with
`ThreadWithExc` from [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/1202745) you linked earlier?
It works if the loop is busy pure Python(eg no `sleep`), otherwise I'd switch to `multiprocessing` and kill subprocess.  Here is the code that hopefully exits gracefully(*nix only):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from signal import signal, SIGTERM
import time

def on_sigterm(*va):
    raise SystemExit

def fun():
    signal(SIGTERM, on_sigterm)
    try:
        for i in xrange(5):
            print 'tick', i
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        print 'graceful cleanup'

if __name__=='__main__':
    proc = Process(target=fun)
    proc.start()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    proc.terminate()
    proc.join()
```